# How do you get rid of flies that like to hang out on the side of my house in the sun?

Tags: exterior

Each year as it gets nicer outside, I begin to find flies congregating in the sun on the side of the house just outside our patio door. It tends to be a nice sunny place for them.  I do not have a grill and I have potted herbs that are supposed to be things they don't like based on other websites.  It's not unusual for small fuzzy bumble bees to also hang out in the same place, so I'm reluctant to spray it since I need the bees to pollinate my vegetable garden and flowers.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you talking about [common house flies](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Housefly), or some other flying insect?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an ecological solution, then bear in mind that many types of lizard (and chameleons) feed off flies. Since they also like to hang out on sunny walls, you may have a meeting of minds here. This is why such animals are usually welcome in homes in sunny places such as Valencia, Spain (called "dracs").

Just remember that cats also like to eat lizards, so this will only work in a feline-free area.